# How to get type inference working in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I have this function with several signature overloads.

```
// 1: overwrite
function extend<T>(d: T, ...s: Partial<T>[]): T;

// 2: shallow copy & overwrite
function extend<T>(o: {}, d: T, ...s: Partial<T>[]): T;

// 3: overwrite & extend
function extend<T, S extends T>(d: T, ...s: Partial<S>[]): Partial<S>;

// 4: shallow copy & overwrite & extend
function extend<T, S extends T>(o: {}, d: T, ...s: Partial<S>[]): Partial<S>;

// implementation
function extend(d: any, ...s: any[]): any {
    for (let src of s) {
        for (let prop in src) {
            if (src.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                d[prop] = src[prop];
            }
        }
    }
    return d;
}
```

In order to make development easier I would like to have code completion for all of them also by means of type inference.

Signature 1 one works flawlessly. Type inference is supported and I get code completion when I start typing properties of `s` objects.

I also understand that type inference isn't possible for signatures 3 and 4 as type `S` can't be inferred from anywhere especially since parameters are of type `Partial<S>`.

But I'm not sure about **signature 2**. It seems that it should be possible to infer types for `S` based on second parameter, which isn't the case unless I explicitly provide generic type parameter.

### Question

How can I accomplish type inference (and code completion) for 1 and 2 at the same time? Or why it's not possible? Part of the problem that I see is that I don't know how to make type alias for empty object literal. Because I think that would be the solution to signature 2.

Comment: The problem I see is that the overloads are very ambiguous and they provide little value because they can fall through one to the other very easily.. I tried to see how to get them to work, but from what I saw if the 2nd overload is not satisfied it will just fall through to the 3rd or 4th, so the second provides little value.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir any suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused about the point of these signatures; can you explain their intent?  Looking at the implementation of `extend()`, it looks like you're re-creating [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).  Is that it?  If so, you might want to look at [how TypeScript declares signatures for `Object.assign()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L300).

Comment: @jcalz: Basically yes because `Object.assign` isn't really available in my code. But looking at call signatures they're very rudimentary, because they assume one will always *extend* `target` not necessarily overwrite its properties. This simply means there's no code completion on source objects even though most of the time assign/extend is being used to overwrite properties or add some that are missing but still stay within type definition of `target`.

Comment: Maybe have multiple functions for multiple purposes?  I mean, the name "extend" is probably not great if you don't want to extend the target; the implementation should probably be different too, since you should maybe only enumerate properties of the target instead of those of the sources...

Comment: Also, do you really want the return value of `extend()` to not depend on the type of `o`?  I would think that if `o` is of type `O`, then the return value of `extend()` should be a subtype of `O`.  Or is `o` always meant to be an empty object?